# External refer using xr with renamed section name (not \arabic , with \Alph), (in overleaf)

Tags: cross-referencing, renewcommand, xr

In my supplementary, I rename the section from `\arabic` to `\Alph`.
And, I cross refer the Supplementary section and figure in main article.

And, ref call all section number also including section name `\Alph` and `\arabic` like **A.3** ref_name **1.3**

How correct labeling without old numbering and section(figure) name?

Follow Image is output of compile.
[image]

## TeX

```
% In Supplementary
%%%%%%% Section Numbering with Alphabet %%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

```
% In Main article
\usepackage{xr} % Add for external referencing from supplementary
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
\typeout{(#1)}% latexmk will find this if $recorder=0
% however, in that case, it will ignore #1 if it is a .aux or 
% .pdf file etc and it exists! If it doesn't exist, it will appear 
% in the list of dependents regardless)
%
% Write the following if you want it to appear in \listfiles 
% --- although not really necessary and latexmk doesn't use this
%
\@addtofilelist{#1}
%
% latexmk will find this message if #1 doesn't exist (yet)
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}

\myexternaldocument{Supplementary}
...
Supplementary Figure \ref{fig:Supp.EventActivity} shows difference of pullrequest and fork events. A fork events are significantly different with other non-development event --- pullrequest, issues and issuecomment (Also, see 
 Supp.\ref{secS4:ActivityDistribution} Fig. S\ref{fig:Supp.EventActivity}).
```

Comment: do not show only snippets. Always make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.